# Loop through Controls by taborder

Tags: vb.net

Today I asked for a help on looping through all Controls on form on order to reference NumericUpDown's and this was an accepted answer:

```
Dim errors As String = ""
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    Dim num = TryCast(ctrl, NumericUpDown)
    If num IsNot Nothing AndAlso (num.Value < 1 OrElse num.Value > 50) Then
         errors += ctrl.Name + " is out of range." + Environment.NewLine
    End If
Next
```

Later by developing my program I realized that NumericUpDown's are listed in (for me) unknown order and this is not wanted result.
I would like/need that NumericUpDown's will be looped by index of tab order.

Any suggestion how to get that with remark that linq is not available because this application is targeted for .NET framework 2.0.

Comment: Are these controls created dynamically? Or have you them designed through the Form Designer? In the latter case you could prepare an array of your controls and put them in the order you like, The loop is then enormously simplified.

Comment: Controlls are created through designer, not dinamically. Can you show a code for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have three NumericUpDown controls defined in the designer and named `numericUpDown1,numericUpDown2,numericUpDown3`
Now declare a global variable in the form class

```
Public Class MyForm

    Dim numUpDnList(2) As NumericUpDown
    ....
```

Then in your code (possibly in the form load event) add them at the array variable in the order that you require

```
Protected Sub MyForm_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Form.Load

      numUpDnList(0) = numericUpDown1
      numUpDnList(1) = numericUpDown3
      numUpDnList(2) = numericUpDown2

End Sub
```

At this point, whenever you need to enumerate these controls, the code is pretty simple

```
Dim errors As String = ""
For Each num In numUpDnList
    If (num.Value < 1 OrElse num.Value > 50) Then
         errors += num.Name + " is out of range." + Environment.NewLine
    End If
Next
```

There is also another way to loop over the Controls collection using the [GetNextControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) method that follows the TabOrder.

```
Dim errors as String
Dim ctrl = Me.GetNextControl(f, true)
while ctrl IsNot Nothing
    Dim num = TryCast(ctrl, NumericUpDown)
    If num IsNot Nothing AndAlso (num.Value < 1 OrElse num.Value > 50) Then
        errors += ctrl.Name + " is out of range." + Environment.NewLine
     End If        
     ctrl = f.GetNextControl(ctrl, true)
End While
```

Comment: Well Steve, I would wait some time in order to get maybe more generic solution. Isn't here a way to force "for each" to loop on some predictable order? By Control.TabIndex or even by Control.Name?

Comment: No AFAIK, if you can't use Linq you are forced to sort the controls using your own rule. See the implementation of a custom IComparer class in the [Array.Sort example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.80).aspx) But this seems to be more trouble than you really need for this case. I always prefer to use simple and understandable solutions if there is no specific requirement to create a more generic logic.

Comment: Thank you for helping Steve but I can't belive that simple and more generic way here don't exists like it was in VB6. For example if command SelectNextControl "knows" which is the next (or previous) control by Tab Index then here "should" be some direct way to loop controls by that without workarrounds. If I don't fint that solution then I will use your suggestion with array of NUD-s.

Comment: You have reminded me that there is a method called [GetNextControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) that could be helpful, but you don't have much of 'control' on the control returned only TabOrder will be followed and there is still the problem to generically find the first control in the taborder

Comment: Ok Steve, I see and I will accept your first answer. I get it working. Then I will see with other options, this one with GetNextControl sounds interesting too. Thanks.